# In Drupal 7, What is a good approach to copy the image from one imagefield to another imagefield?

Tags: javascript, media

I'd like to allow the user to upload an image once, and have it apply to 3 other image fields on the same page without requiring the user to submit the form. Afterwards I intend to apply different croppings to each image but that may not be related to this question.

Is there an existing module or solution to this? If not, what is a good place to inject this behavior client side?

Comment: Why not just use one image field and show it's images in 3 places?

Comment: Because there are 3 different cropping possibilities. The user is prompted to crop each image via the module Imagefield Crop 7.x-1.x (not 2.x)

Answer (score 1):

You should only use one image field, and then setup 3 *image styles* at:

> admin/config/media/image-styles

For each image style you can define a number of different actions, like cropping. When displaying the image you can use [theme_image_style()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7)

This is a part of Drupal core and can be extended by e.g. [ImageCache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions).

Comment: This is not the correct answer because it needs to be a client side affect.

Comment: Ok. You should state that in your question. And maybe, don't use the term "client side", as most developers will relate this to JavaScript.

Comment: I am referring to JavaScript. This is mentioned in two places in the question: "I'd like to allow the user to upload an image once, and have it apply to 3 other image fields on the same page without requiring the user to submit the form." and "Is there an existing module or solution to this? If not, what is a good place to inject this behavior client side?"